Einstein Bot: Conversation Message Definition ID: bad value for restricted picklist field
I’m trying to deploy an Einstein Bot that uses several Messaging Components. However, I’m encountering the following error for one of them: Conversation Message Definition ID: bad value for restricted picklist field: MessagingComponentName.
The issue seems unusual because my Messaging Component is not a restricted picklist, and I could deploy it to a different environment without any problems.
Has anyone else experienced this issue? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Workaround
Create two deployments:

First, all components related to Einstein Bot, e.g. ConversationMessagingDefinition, ApexClass, and all other metadata used in Einstein Bot.
Second only with Einstein Bot.

